# Standalone parameter in XML being generated on Jetty but not on JBOSS

Tags: java, xml, xslt, jetty

Below is my code snippet generating an XML in Java. I am using jdk1.8.0_152 and the following sample is used to construct an XML element.

```
DocumentBuilder dBuilder= DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(writer));
returnXML = writer.toString();
```

The above code returns

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><TYPE>star</TYPE>
```

on JBossAS [6.1.0],while it returns

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><TYPE>star</TYPE>
```

on Jetty9.1.
Not sure what am I missing.The Document class and the underlying TransformerFactory should be the same since we are using the same Java1.8 for both.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, the jaxp API will search the classpath for "providers". When it finds the highest priority provider on the classpath, it uses that implementation. If no provider is found on the classpath, it will default to using the JVM-provided implementation (the system-default).

See [DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#newInstance()) for more info on this process.

Here is how the two containers you mention differ (out of the box):

**JBoss AS 6.1** - JBoss comes with Xerces 2.9.1 which is a jaxp service provider

**Jetty** - no jaxp service provider is packaged with Jetty, so jaxp defaults to the JVM-provided implementation

In this specific case, the JVM-provided implementation is adding the `standalone` attribute that you refer to.

Comment: Just to confirm @rmlan, Jetty does not include an XML provider (and uses the JVM default for its own XML uses as well).

Comment: Right, that is what I meant by "which would be chosen over the system-default implementation, which is what is chosen in the case of Jetty." I'll clarify the other line that mentions the Jetty provider.

Comment: Just confirming your "guess", that's all.

Comment: The reason I left it as a "guess" is there is no telling what OP may have put in the lib directory of either Jetty or JBoss (people do crazy things with webapp classloading).

Answer (score 0):

@rmlan 
Thanks for the details above.
After carefully debugging I see how different TransformerFactoryImpl are being picked up by JBOSS and Jetty.

JBOSS uses the TransformerFactoryImpl from `org.apache.xalan.processor (xalan2.7.1.jar)`

Jetty  uses the TransformerFactoryImpl from `com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax(rt.jar)`

I am trying to force Jetty to use the xalan jar from apache by loading it to the jetty classpath.
Adding the xalan jar to Jetty_HOME/lib (and restarting the app) did not seem to work in my case.